# python regex to get particular word

Tags: python, python-re

I am new to python and I am not familiar with regex pattern.
I am using re package to get particular text in my code. but it doesn't seems to work.
please help!

```
import re

text = '<pre><a href="1.sh">1.sh'

filename = re.match(r'\D+="[*]"\D', text)

print(text)
print(filename)
```

**output:**

```
<pre><a href="1.sh">1.sh
None
```

I am expecting the filename '1.sh', it can be either the text within double quote or the text after '>'

1.sh

also in my scenario, the filename varies, it may be filename.txt or number.ps1 or number.sh

Comment: sorry, forgot to add my expected output... I am expecting the filename --> 1.sh
also filename varies in my scenario, it may have *.txt text.ps1, its not always, number.sh

Comment: Please edit the question to show the expected output, rather than (only) putting it in the comments.

Comment: Also please confirm that what you are trying to match is the link target rather than the link text (as they are both the same here).

Comment: @alaniwi Sorry, I don't see an edit option.. I am still searching...

Comment: Under the question you should see some links (share, edit, follow, flag).

Comment: @alaniwi done, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

text = '<pre><a href="1.sh">1.sh'

filename = re.search(r'(?<=href=")[^"]+', text).group()

print(text)
print(filename)
```

**Output:**

```
<pre><a href="1.sh">1.sh
1.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import re
text='<pre><a href="1.sh">1.sh'
filename=re.sub('^<[ ]*a[ ]+.*href[ ]*=[ ]*',  '', re.sub('.*>$', '', text).strip('"')
```